# Angular2: dynamically making parts of a text clickable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a text with hashtags inside. I want to make these tags clickable.
I created a pipe that will mark all tags with cssClass hashTag. Now I need to handle click events on these tags

Here is a sample code

```
import {Component, NgModule} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'
import {eigonic} from './hashtag'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [innerHtml]="txt|hash"></h2>

    </div>
  `,
  pipes:[eigonic.Hashtag],
})
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.txt = 'This is a #simple post on #Angular !'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and here is the pipe

```
import {Pipe} from '@angular/core';

export module eigonic {
    @Pipe({ name: 'hash' })
    export class Hashtag {    
        transform(value: string): string {
            return value == undefined ? value : value.replace(new RegExp('(#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', 'g'), '<span btn clear class="hashTag" >$1</span>'); 
        }

    }
}
```

and a plunkr in case you want to play around.

https://plnkr.co/edit/vT1MrJNsupkBrhIMQ6qv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use HostListener for this purpose like this:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('hashTag')) {
    alert('HashTag!');
  }
}
```

Here's your forked and updated [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/sq9t0v0NI9ZQL0VZL3ja?p=preview)
Check out `src/app.ts`.
More on HostListener in the [docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/HostListener-var.html)