# Ionic - Can I navigate through a pipe

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a pipe to link and text with starts with a hash or an @ but navPush doesn't seem to work. Can I navigate based on a condition in a pipe?

Here is my pipe where I would like to link normal text.

```
import {Injectable, Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
    name: 'tags'
})
@Injectable()
export class TagsPipe implements PipeTransform {
// Pages
mePage = "MePage";
transform(value: string): string {
    return value == undefined ? value : value
        .replace(new RegExp('(#[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', 'g'),'<a [navPush]="mePage" [navParams]="params" class="hashtag">$1</a>')
        .replace(new RegExp('(@[A-Za-z0-9-_]+)', 'g'),'<a [navPush]="mePage" [navParams]="params" class="usertag">$1</a>');
}}
```

In this case "MePage" is a sample page which uses lazy loading and is already successfully loaded without any issue when not using a pipe.

Comment: Can you show the `pipe's` usage? where you use it?

Comment: There is no need at all to add `@Injectable()` when there is already `@Pipe()`, `@Component()`, or `@Directive()`.

Comment: Angular doesn't process HTML added dynamically in any way. If you don't apply DomSanitizer to sanitize the HTML it might strip HTML tags from the string. It definitely won't apply directives, bindings, or components to HTML added this way.

Comment: I simply use it in photo caption. I want to link captions like "great pic #landscape" where if you click on #landspace you go to a different page

Comment: Is there a way to DomSanitize?

Comment: Note that I tried to show the pipe using outer html (in my case <p [outerHTML]="photo.desc | tags"></p>) and the css classes show but [navPush] does not work. Also the injectable is there because I used ionic generate to create a new pipe

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051150/angular2-dynamically-making-parts-of-a-text-clickable and use host listener.

Answer (score 0):

check out [www.stackoverflow.com/questions/39051150/](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/39051150/)… and use host listener.